# MySQL: How to get result from 2 different tables with 1 WHERE IN CLAUSE

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables with different content and there is no way to join tables because there is no common identifier, but every table as 1 column with same content. I need to extract the content from these both colums and want to get ID's from each record that is the same. The following query extracts what I already know/have, but I don't get the ID's from the WHERE IN table.

**Query**

```
SELECT pd.products_id, pd.products_short_description 
FROM products_description pd
WHERE pd.products_short_description IN (SELECT m.manufacturers_ean FROM manufacturers m)
```

**Result**

```
ID | products_short_description
-------------------------------
2  | BMW
```

**This is what I need:**

```
ID | products_short_description | ID | manufacturers_ean
--------------------------------------------------------
2  | BMW                        | 285| BMW
```

Comment: Please add another table also.

Comment: Can you pleas Show sample data?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT pd.products_id, pd.products_short_description, m.manufacturers_id, m.manufacturers_ean
FROM products_description pd INNER JOIN manufacturers m ON pd.products_short_description = m.manufacturers_ean;
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case What you do with where could be done whit inner join and so you could select the two column from manufacturers_ean   too

```
SELECT pd.products_id, pd.products_short_description, m.ID m.manufacturers_ean
FROM products_description pd
INNER JOIN manufacturers m on m.manufacturers_ean  = pd.products_short_description
```

Answer (score 0):

Query Will be :

```
 SELECT pd.products_id, pd.products_short_description, m.ID, m.manufacturers_ean
    FROM products_description pd,manufacturers m 
    WHERE m.manufacturers_ean = pd.products_short_description
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to all: Perfect! It works! Where an I mark it as solved?